# Saving line from file to variable in Makefile

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to save variable `line` to variable `line_info`.
When I echo `line` there is no problem, but if I try to assign it to `line_info` and then do an echo of `line_info` I get only "ine". Can anybody please help.

```
define func_run_regression
@while read -r line; do \
    echo "$$line";\
    $(eval line_info = $$line) \
    echo "$$line"; \
done <"$1"
endef
```

Comment: What are you *actually* trying to solve? You seem to be mixing shell recipes and GNU make directives. That's confusing.

Comment: Also notice that your `$(eval )` is evaluated at the point of use of your `func_run_regression` but in any case inside make still. It is _not_ evaluated during but _before_ the execution of your shell commands and thus can never have the input value of `$line`. In fact, at the point where make will give the command line to the shell, `$(line_info)` will carry the value `$line`.